# Error in script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am new to bash and scripting and I am trying to create a simple script but for some reason it won't let me run this:

```
fileCount= ls -1 | wc -l

#echo $fileCount

for (( i=0; i<$fileCount; ++i )) ; do
 echo item: $i
done
```

Whenever I try to run this it just gives me an error message saying it expected an operand.
I am really confused on the error here and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the entire error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your code running with minimal change, replace:

```
fileCount= ls -1 | wc -l
```

With:

```
fileCount=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
```

`$(...)`  is called *command substitution*.  It is what you use when you want capture the output of a command in a variable.

It is very important that there be no spaces on either side of the equal sign.

#### Improvements

- To speed up the result, use the `-U` option to turn off sorting.
- To prevent any attempt to display special characters, use `-q`.

Thus:

```
fileCount=$(ls -1Uq | wc -l)
```

Lastly, when `ls` is writing to something other than a terminal, such as, in this command, a pipeline, it prints one file name per line.  This makes  `-1` optional.

Answer (score 1):

you missed to assign the output of `wc -l` to your variable. Try this:

```
fileCount=$(ls | wc -l)
```

(option "-1" is not needed, because `ls` writes one file per line if its stdout is not a terminal)